# Variable passed by reference to anonymous function not mutating

Tags: php

In a much simplified case I have this code below:

```
$ojson = [];

$finish = function() use ($ojson) {
    print json_encode($ojson);
    exit();
}

$addError = function($msg) use (&$ojson, $finish) {
    $ojson['error'] = $msg;
    $finish();
}

$addError('rawr');
```

However it is printing an empty array (`[]`) instead of `{"error": "rawr"}`. I did pass `$ojson` to `$addError` by reference, which makes me baffled as to why it wont work.

Comment: [*"use() parameters are early binding - they use the **variable's value at the point where the lambda function is declared**, rather than the point where the lambda function is called (late binding)."*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Ooo wow so interesting! Thanks @Rizier123 so simply changing them to by reference in `$finish` will do the trick, thanks! If you move to solution I would love to accept.